# Recycler View is not Displaying Data in Card View

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i have created an app in which i want to show data from firebase in  recycler view using card view.My data is being retrieved from firebase and is playing till recycler option reached but not displaying data in card view .Here is my code.Please help me out with this in order to display data in recycler view ......

package com.example.dpka.intern;

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class frag2ofAttendanceNew extends Fragment {

    String mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance;
    String yearf1;
    String monthf1;


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    DatabaseReference holidaysRef;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.d("abcd","oncreate view reached");
        final View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag2of_attendance_new, container, false);
        Log.d("abcd","oncreate view reached and layout inflated");
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("abcd","onstart reached");
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        if(b!=null){
            mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance = b.getString("mPinToFrag2ofAttendance");
            Log.d("abcd","Receiving from frag1ofAttendance");
            yearf1 = b.getString("year");
            monthf1 = b.getString("month");
        }
        Log.d("abcd",mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance);
Log.d("abcd",yearf1);
Log.d("abcd",monthf1);
        /*myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://esscurrent-77906.firebaseio.com/Attendance_Records/123456/2018/3");*/


        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Attendance_Records").child(mPinFromFrag1ofAttendance).child(yearf1).child(monthf1);


        /*myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child("year").exists()){
                    Log.d("abcd","datasnapshot year exists");

                    String tryyear = dataSnapshot.child("year").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("abcd",tryyear);

                    *//*Attendance_Records value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Attendance_Records.class);
                    String a = value.getYear();
                    TextView abc = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tryyear);
                    abc.setText(a);
                    String c = abc.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("abcd",c);

//                    Log.d("abcd",a);
                    String b = value.getEntryDate();
                    TextView bcd = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tryentrydate);
                    bcd.setText(b);*//*
  //                  Log.d("abcd",b);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
*/

        Log.d("abcd","DB reference reached");
        //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        Log.d("abcd","setlayoutmanager");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Attendance_Records>().setQuery(myRef,Attendance_Records.class).build();
        Log.d("abcd","recycleroptions reached");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Attendance_Records,AttendanceViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Attendance_Records, AttendanceViewHolder>
                        (options) {
            //Log.d("abcd","recycleradapter reached");

             @NonNull
             @Override
             public AttendanceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                 Log.d("abcd","oncreateviewholder reached");
                 View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
                 Log.d("abcd","cardview inflated");
                 return new AttendanceViewHolder(view);
             }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(AttendanceViewHolder holder, int position, Attendance_Records model) {

                holidaysRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Holidays");
                final String userdate = model.getDate();
                holidaysRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(userdate).exists()){
                            Log.d("abcd","date matched");
                            //String holidaytype = holidaysRef.child(userdate).toString();
                            final DatabaseReference tilldateRef = holidaysRef.child(userdate);
                            tilldateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                                    if(dataSnapshot1.child("G").exists()){
                                        Log.d("abcd","its G");
                                        CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                                        Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
                                        cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                                        Log.d("abcd","changed cv color");
                                    }
                                    else if(dataSnapshot1.child("R").exists()){
                                        Log.d("abcd","its R");
                                        CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                                        Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
                                        cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                                        Log.d("abcd","changed cv color");
                                    }



                                    else{
                                        Log.d("abcd","Neither G nor R");
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                            /*if(tilldateRef.child("G")){
                                Log.d("abcd","its G");
                                CardView cv = getView().findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                                Log.d("abcd","cardview found");
                                cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                                Log.d("abcd","changed cv color");
                            }*/
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                holder.setYear(model.getYear());
                holder.setMonth(model.getMonth());
                holder.setDate(model.getDate());
                holder.setIntime(model.getInTime());
                holder.setOuttime(model.getOutTime());
                holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
                holder.setEntrydate(model.getEntryDate());
                holder.setMyid(model.getMyID());
                Log.d("abcd","onbindviewholder reached");
            }


        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }

    public class AttendanceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView vhyear, vhmonth, vhdate, vhintime, vhouttime, vhentrydate, vhstatus, vhmyid;
        public AttendanceViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            Log.d("abcd","attendanceviewholder reached");
            vhyear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
            vhmonth = itemView.findViewById(R.id.month);
            vhdate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            vhintime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inTime);
            vhouttime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.outTime);
            vhentrydate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.entryDate);
            vhstatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            vhmyid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userId);
            Log.d("abcd","textviews found");

        }

        public void setYear(String year) {
            Log.d("abcd","setyear reached");
            vhyear.setText(year);
            Log.d("abcd",vhyear.getText().toString());
        }

        public void setMonth(String month) {
            Log.d("abcd","setmonth reached");
            vhmonth.setText(month);
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            Log.d("abcd","setdate reached");
            vhdate.setText(date);
        }

        public void setIntime(String inTime) {
            Log.d("abcd","setintime reached");
            vhintime.setText(inTime);
        }

        public void setOuttime(String outTime) {
            Log.d("abcd","setouttime reached");
            vhouttime.setText(outTime);
        }

        public void setEntrydate(String entrydate){
            Log.d("abcd","setentrydate reached");
            vhentrydate.setText(entrydate);
        }

        public void setStatus(String status){
            Log.d("abcd","setstatus reached");
            vhstatus.setText(status);
        }

        public void setMyid(String myid){
            Log.d("abcd","setmyid reached");
            vhmyid.setText(myid);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: not getting what you are saying!!

Comment: check if you POJO fields are the same as in the database

Comment: yes they are exactly same